# Problems getting Durandal using Bower

Tags: durandal

We are using Durandal in our app and we use bower to fetch the dependencies. Now we started to get this error when trying to install dependencies in our project:

```
bower durandal#2.2.0  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal-Bower.git", exit code of #128 remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal-Bower.git/'
```

It is weird because it was working well.

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the repository has been archived (seems like the project has been replaced by Aurelia).

You will need to download it, create a new GitHub project, and point Bower to use it.